# Add count as property to javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

- one with `categories`
- one with `datarecords`

Every data record belongs to a specific category.

With every use of a filter (e.g. `searchfield`) on the `datarecords`, I want to add the total count of records per category to each `category-object`, so I can display them on every `tab-pane` (e.g. `text: Algemeen`, `value: 'general`, `countFiltered: 2`)

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/ukgs5dy7/) for this.

Till now I get no count-filtered, locally I get a constant error corresponding to line 78 in my fiddle:

> Uncaught (in promise) Type Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That kind of error that has the worst description ever?

Comment: I think the question actually makes sense, you just have to read it slower. When he searches he wants the number of results for each category to show up on the pane of that category, kind of like a facebook badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is here:

```
var filtered = results.filter(function (results) {
    return (results.category.toLowerCase() == this.categories[cat].value.toLowerCase());
});
```

You can either pass in a `thisArg` to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filtered = results.filter(function (results) {
    return (results.category.toLowerCase() == this.categories[cat].value.toLowerCase());
}, this);
```

or in ES6 you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var filtered = results.filter(
    results => results.category.toLowerCase() == this.categories[cat].value.toLowerCase() 
);
```

Comment: Solved it! Why do you need to pass a thisArg? Does it apply to the results in my vue-model?

Comment: @BFlyDesign A closure has access to outer-scoped variables only if they aren't shadowed by it's own variables, but every time a function is called in Javascript the value of `this` inside it is set, so unlike other variables `this` is always shadowed. If you pass in a second argument you are telling `filter` that you want `this` inside your callback to be whatever you passed in. In your case you passed in `this` from outside the callback, so even though the callback still has it's own `this` shadowing the outer `this`, it refers to the same object.

Comment: what do I need to change in my fiddle to let it automaticaly update the count when using the searchfield?

Comment: @BFlyDesign I'd never heard of Vue until now, so I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it seems like you just need to call `tokens.countFiltered` from your filter. See the update here: https://jsfiddle.net/ukgs5dy7/9/

Comment: not completely working as intended but you've put me on the right track! Thx